# Does there exist a local homeomorphism between these two set?

Tags: general-topology

We have to decide if there is a local homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ and (X$\times$Z), where X=$\mathbb{C}^{2}$ with metric topology and Z=$\mathbb{C}^{2}$ with cofinite topology. Here is my attempt at it:

If there was a local homeomorphism between g: $\mathbb{R}^{4}$$\rightarrow$(X$\times$Z) then for x$_{0}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, there will be an open set U $\subseteq$$\mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that g(U) is homeomorphic to U. However, U in metric topology is Hausdorff whereas g(U)$\subseteq$(X$\times$Z) can not be Hausdorff because (X$\times$Z) is not Hausdorff.

I also have a separate proof that since Z is not Hausdorff in cofinite topology, (X$\times$Z) is not Hausdorff. I would really appreciate any comments on this.

Comment: correct correct correct

Comment: thank you very much @foreverMozart